# Create collection from input array

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Lets say I have a form that is a invoice. It has line items like $product[$key], $quantity[$key]. So when the form is submitted the input looks like

```
{
  customer_id : "214"
  product_id: [ "1","5", "6" ],
  quantity: ["34", "1", "54"]
}
```

I have a model for that details table. What I have been doing is iterating over it and creating a details object then saving it like this

```
foreach($product as $key=>$p)
{
  if($p)
  {
    $t = new Details;
    $t->product = $p;
    $t->quantity = $quantity[$key];
    $t->save();
  }
}
```

I'm guessing there is a way to be much more efficient about this. Like creating a collection of details straight from the input but I have no idea how I would accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate models through mass assignment.

```
$details = new Details(['product_id'=>'1','quantity'=>'34']);
```

You can also specify columns of the table that you do not want to be mass assigned using the $guarded variable in the model.

Check out mass assignment in Laravel's docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

For your particular issue it looks like you would need to build your input array out of the elements of the other arrays.

Comment: Right. That is essentially what I'm doing, just with more lines of code. What I want to do is create a collection of detail objects so I can do something like `order->details()->saveMany($details);`

Answer (score 0):

Seems it isn't possible. [Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1295) is Taylor responding to a issue request. It seems the problem is it wouldn't be possible to fire events then. I just ended up doing

```
  $d = array();
    foreach ($details as $detail) {
        $d[] = new OrderDetail($detail);
    }
  $order->details()->saveMany($d);
```